# Why is Chef using local IP address to synchronize my cookbooks?

Tags: chef-infra

For a server that is not on my local network and that I succesfully bootstrapped I noticed that Chef will try to synchronize cookbooks using the local IP address. Is this by design? It doesn't make sense.

So for example when I do

```
knife ssh collab "sudo chef-client" --manual-list --ssh-user user  --ssh-password '***'
```

This will fail with error message for example

```
collab Starting Chef Client, version 11.18.6
collab resolving cookbooks for run list: ["ok"]
collab Synchronizing Cookbooks:
collab [2015-04-22T08:35:12+02:00] ERROR: Error connecting to https://192.168.1.132/bookshelf/organization-bf7e66f665c6aa8c3ae2e3e39bf13aee/checksum-835c9d84484e285baa65e05771e42868?AWSAccessKeyId=e61fd655bf64a6cfa43f147867c9e5aa46fc84b5&Expires=1429713256&Signature=RbykDisyo4qo569Mv9e22WGPf1k%3D, retry 1/5
```

So Chef is using the local IP address of my Chef server 192.168.1.132. Why is it not using the FQDN?

The `chef_server_url` in my local `knife.rb` has the FQDN. Same for the `/etc/chef/client.rb` on the node.

So no where is configured that this IP should be used. Why is Chef doing this?

*Update*

I tried update `/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb`

```
api_fqdn = "chef.mydomain.com"
bookshelf['vip'] = "chef.mydomain.com"
```

After `sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure` I can see my domain name in `/etc/opscode/chef-server-running.json` but the error message remains.

I also tried complete reboot of Chef server machine, just to be sure.

The address still appears in the json file

```
ostraaten@chef:~$ sudo grep '192.168.1.132' /etc/opscode/chef-server-running.json
[sudo] password for ostraaten: 
      "vrrp_instance_ipaddress": "192.168.1.132",   
      "vrrp_instance_vrrp_unicast_bind": "192.168.1.132",
```

*Update*

The log shows the `chef_server_url` is correct now

```
 ....
 collab   Networking Error:
 collab   -----------------
 collab   Error connecting to https://192.168.1.132/bookshelf/organization-bf7e66f665c6aa8c3ae2e3e39bf13aee/checksum-835c9d84484e285baa65e05771e42868?AWSAccessKeyId=e61fd655bf64a6cfa43f147867c9e5aa46fc84b5&Expires=1429721409&Signature=BiPwn2iUia3klWTYQGwKDPs8kAQ%3D - Connection timed out - connect(2)
.... (lines deleted)
collab   
collab   Your chef_server_url may be misconfigured, or the network could be down.
collab   
collab   Relevant Config Settings:
collab   -------------------------
collab   chef_server_url  "https://chef.mydomain.com/organizations/gbx"
```

Comment: What is the result of `grep '192.168.1.132' /etc/opscode/chef-server-running.json` ?

Comment: Is shows `192.168.1.132` see update

Comment: Seems you're in a HA topology, see [this](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_server_optional_settings.html#keepalived)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is targeting `bookshelf`, the s3 like store service of chef server.

For it to use a virtual IP (NAT from a firewall or specific interface on the server) you have to tweak the `chef-server.rb` file see [this documentation](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_server.html).

The file is located under `/etc/opscode` for chef 12 and enterprise chef 11

If you're on open source chef server 11 it is under `/etc/chef-server`.

You may see the actual configuration in the same place in a file named `chef-server-running.json` (the format is a little different but you'll see the keys you need to change)

Keys to change to use a VIP:

```
api_fqdn = "my_server.domain.local"
bookshelf['vip'] = "my_server.domain.local"
```

After this run `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` and check any remaining local IP/hostname in the .json file.

In case of a HA topology there's some other config options to set according to [this](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_server_optional_settings.html#keepalived):

```
keepalived['vrrp_instance_ipaddress'] = "IP to return"
```

This should be enough.

---

For information in my particular case (**Warning** I'm using chef server 11 open source) I've ended with:

```
bookshelf['ha'] = true
bookshelf['vip'] = "server.domain.local"
bookshelf['url'] = "https://server.domain.local"
bookshelf['listen'] = "0.0.0.0"
chef_expander['ha']  = true
chef_solr['ha'] = true
erchef['ha'] = true
lb['vip'] = "my vip (existing vrrp IP on the server)"
lb['api_fqdn'] = 'myserver.domain.local'
lb['web_ui_fqdn']  = 'myserver.domain.local'
lb['debug'] = false
nginx['ha']  = true
nginx['server_name'] = 'myserver.domain.local'
nginx['url'] = 'https://myserver.domain.local'
nginx['non_ssl_port']=800
postgresql['ha']  = true
rabbitmq['ha']  = true
chef_server_webui['ha']  = true
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the `ProxyPreserveHost On` and this fixed it for me ;)